# Why my mouseover code not working, how can i fix it

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I want fetch opening odds 1xBet on [https://www.oddsportal.com/football/chile/segunda-division/real-san-joaquin-linares-unido-tOuhZVip/#ht-ft;2;27 but code is not working](https://stackoverflow.com).

```
hda = 1;
bookmaker= '1xBet';
els = document.getElementsByClassName('flex');
for (var i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(els[i].innerText.startsWith(bookmaker) && els[i].innerText.endsWith(`%`)) {
        el = els[i].children[hda].children[0];
        event = new Event('mouseover');
        el.dispatchEvent(event);
        break;          
    }
}
```

I tried mouseover to odd with code but it says 'undefined' is there anyone help me. I want mouseover to 1xBet odd like this [https://prnt.sc/-wmcc-VGXBwH](https://stackoverflow.com) .

Comment: What says undefined specifically?

Comment: Actually im using this code on WebHarvy for fetch opening odds but when i run the code nothings happen. I tried it on console it says 'undefined', but code is working on '1X2' and 'Over/Under' tabs.